# Enterprise Library with VS2005

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, visual-studio-2005, enterprise-library

i'll work in a new project using visual studio 2005, .net framework 3.5 and enterprise library 5, there is any problem with this configuration? cause searching for the EL4.1 and EL5.0 both need VS2008 or later.

Comment: .Net 3.1 does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I've edited it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its seems that EL 5.0 Works without problem with VS2005, just if the .NET 3.5 is Installed.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2005 does not support .Net 3.5.

You need 2008, or preferably 2010.
You can get the [express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express) for free.

Comment: Hi, i know that VS2005 doesn´t support .NET 3.5 but if i've installed this version also .net 2.0 is installed (3.5 is an extension to .net2.0). The problem is that my company only has licensed vs2005.